# Custom Slider control in windows store 8 app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to edit the default style of Slider control in windows 8 app.

Need to customize the slider as per my requirement. 
I want the slider like the following[image]

I tried with the style given in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709929.aspx) , but it only supports windows8.1 app, but mine is windows 8 app.

Can anybody help me to edit the default style.

Thank you.
Noorul.

Comment: Right click on the slider in the designer (I like to use the Document Outline for this) and choose Edit Template... then Edit a Copy... and the designer will generate a copy of the existing template for you to edit. Is there a reason you're still writing Windows 8 apps and not 8.1?

Comment: Hi Rob , thanks for your comment, My requirement is like that, so only I am developing for windows 8.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have tried to add a Textblock inside that control template, but its not fit with the width of the slider. Any idea?